# Outgoing-Call-Connected event (Android)

Tags: android, mobile

Currently i am listening to the "onCallStateChanged"-event, detecting the following:

- IDLE -> OFFHOOK (Call attempt)
- OFFHOOK -> IDLE (Call finished)

Afterwards i read the CallLog for more information about the call like the duration and so on....

As you see, i only detect the start and the end of a call. But i also need the information about when a call is connected.

Does someone know if it is possible to detect if a call is connected?